# How to debug server side script for file uploading from client (curl at this example)?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am trying to write a Perl Mojolicious request from CLI. I want to pass a file as a parameter to this request.
Below are the things I have tried so far, but no avail.

Below Example is what working fine with me.

```
curl (working):          curl -X POST "http://localhost:3000/uploadtest.pl/status?Token=6d949625-2f07-1e7a-d57a-de0fa949035d"
Mojolicious (working):  perl ./uploadtest.pl get -v -M POST /status?"Token=3780e99a-fc2c-54e5-2c31-417f945c1792"
```

Below is the the example in which i am stuck, becouse below perl script take file as a input [file upload]:

```
curl (working):          curl -X POST -F Input_File=@d:/xml/test.xml "http://localhost:3000/uploadtest.pl/upload?Input_Type=XML
Mojolicious (not working):  perl ./uploadtest.pl get -v -M POST /upload?"Input_Type=XML&Input_File=d:/xml/test.xml"
```

It will be great help if someone helps me out with this.

---

```
#uploadtest.pl

use Mojolicious::Lite;

# Upload form in DATA section
get '/' => 'form';


# Check status
post '/status' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  my $Token = $self->param('Token');
  $self->render(text => "In process: $Token");
};

# Multipart upload handler
post '/upload' => sub {
  my $self = shift;

  # Process uploaded file
  my $Input_File = $self->param('Input_File');
  my $Input_Type = $self->param('Input_Type');
  my $size = $Input_File->size;
  my $name = $Input_File->filename;
  my $upload = $self->req->upload('Input_File');
  $upload->move_to("d:/xml/$name");  #move location
  $self->render(text => "Thanks for uploading $size byte file $name.");
};

app->start;
__DATA__

@@ form.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>File Upload</title></head>
  <body>
  <form name="FileUpload" action="http://localhost:3000/uploadtest.pl/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
       Input Type:</td><td><input type="text" name="Input_Type" />
       Please specify a file:</td><td><input type="file" name="Input_File" size="40"></td></tr>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
   <br><br><br><hr><br><br><br>
  <form name="Status" action="http://localhost:3000/uploadtest.pl/status" method="post">
      Token ID: <input type="text" name="Token" />
     <input type="submit" value="Check Status"/>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I clicked your title I thought this is about passing a file as a commandline argument to the application at startup. Just to clarify, you want to send a request using curl that has the content of a file as its body? Or maybe not. Please [edit] your question and clarify. Also, is the code you show of upload_test.pl?

Comment: I have given curl as well mojolicious command line example which i have tried.Curl is working fine but i dont know how to use command in mojolicious for file content as argument. So could you please tell me how i will passing file as a command argument in mojolicious.

Answer (score 4):

The Mojolicious get command does not support generating requests from files i'm afraid.

```
perl -Mojo -E 'p("http://localhost:3000" => form => {Input_Type => "XML", Input_File => {file => "d:/xml/test.xml"}})'
```

You'd have to use an `ojo` one-liner.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I think you misunderstood my question. The only thing i want is to supply file as an argument to Mojolicious get from CLI. your suggested syntax is not useful for code debugging.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are not understand what `post '/upload'` does and `uploadtest.pl` is.

Your script is a small HTTP server which receive requests and does responses.
You can run your server permanently and do requests with, for example, `curl` or do one request to it and exit.

```
$ perl uploadtest.pl daemon
[Sat Jun 11 14:00:41 2016] [info] Listening at "http://*:3000"
Server available at http://127.0.0.1:3000

# in other shell
$ curl -X POST "http://localhost:3000/uploadtest.pl/status?Token=6d949625-2f07-1e7a-d57a-de0fa949035d"
```

Or both at once:

```
$perl ./uploadtest.pl get -v -M POST /status?"Token=3780e99a-fc2c-54e5-2c31-417f945c1792"
```

These POSTs make requests to permanent (first example) or onetime server (second one) with **empty content**

If you run your curl with `-v` options:

```
$ curl -v -X POST "http://localhost:3000/status?Token=6d949625-2f07-1e7a-d57a-de0fa949035d"
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> POST /status?Token=6d949625-2f07-1e7a-d57a-de0fa949035d HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Mojolicious (Perl) is not blacklisted
< Server: Mojolicious (Perl)
< Date: Sat, 11 Jun 2016 11:42:24 GMT
< Content-Length: 48
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
In process: 6d949625-2f07-1e7a-d57a-de0fa949035d
```

You even may do `tcpdump` while querying your server:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -x -X -i lo port 3000
14:41:51.665032 IP localhost.49063 > localhost.3000: Flags [P.], seq 1:129, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 1097613 ecr 1097613], length 128
    0x0000:  4500 00b4 38c4 4000 4006 037e 7f00 0001  E...8.@.@..~....
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 bfa7 0bb8 3b17 8750 a281 4839  ........;..P..H9
    0x0020:  8018 0156 fea8 0000 0101 080a 0010 bf8d  ...V............
    0x0030:  0010 bf8d 504f 5354 202f 7374 6174 7573  ....POST./status
    0x0040:  3f54 6f6b 656e 3d36 6439 3439 3632 352d  ?Token=6d949625-
    0x0050:  3266 3037 2d31 6537 612d 6435 3761 2d64  2f07-1e7a-d57a-d
    0x0060:  6530 6661 3934 3930 3335 6420 4854 5450  e0fa949035d.HTTP
    0x0070:  2f31 2e31 0d0a 5573 6572 2d41 6765 6e74  /1.1..User-Agent
    0x0080:  3a20 6375 726c 2f37 2e33 352e 300d 0a48  :.curl/7.35.0..H
    0x0090:  6f73 743a 206c 6f63 616c 686f 7374 3a33  ost:.localhost:3
    0x00a0:  3030 300d 0a41 6363 6570 743a 202a 2f2a  000..Accept:.*/*
    0x00b0:  0d0a 0d0a                                ....
```

When you want to upload file to your server you use `-F Input_File=@d:/xml/test.xml` curl option. You also expect you can do same **onetime** request, but next command:

```
$perl ./uploadtest.pl get -v -M POST /upload?"Input_Type=XML&Input_File=d:/xml/test.xml"
```

does not support such option.

```
$perl ./uploadtest.pl help get
Usage: APPLICATION get [OPTIONS] URL [SELECTOR|JSON-POINTER] [COMMANDS]

  ./myapp.pl get /
  ./myapp.pl get -H 'Accept: text/html' /hello.html 'head > title' text
  ./myapp.pl get //sri:secr3t@/secrets.json /1/content
  mojo get mojolicious.org
  mojo get -v -r google.com
  mojo get -v -H 'Host: mojolicious.org' -H 'Accept: */*' mojolicious.org
  mojo get -M POST -H 'Content-Type: text/trololo' -c 'trololo' perl.org
  mojo get mojolicious.org 'head > title' text
  mojo get mojolicious.org .footer all
  mojo get mojolicious.org a attr href
  mojo get mojolicious.org '*' attr id
  mojo get mojolicious.org 'h1, h2, h3' 3 text
  mojo get https://api.metacpan.org/v0/author/SRI /name

Options:
  -C, --charset <charset>     Charset of HTML/XML content, defaults to
                              auto-detection
  -c, --content <content>     Content to send with request
  -H, --header <name:value>   Additional HTTP header
  -h, --help                  Show this summary of available options
      --home <path>           Path to home directory of your application,
                              defaults to the value of MOJO_HOME or
                              auto-detection
  -M, --method <method>       HTTP method to use, defaults to "GET"
  -m, --mode <name>           Operating mode for your application, defaults to
                              the value of MOJO_MODE/PLACK_ENV or
                              "development"
  -r, --redirect              Follow up to 10 redirects
  -v, --verbose               Print request and response headers to STDERR
```

As you can see from help, you can send short text message:

```
  ./uploadtest.pl get -M POST -H 'Content-Type: text/trololo' -c 'trololo' perl.org
```

To upload files into your `uploadtest.pl` server you may write your own uploader. For this need you should use [Mojo::UserAgent](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent) module. [Example](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Large-file-upload)

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;

# Upload file via POST and "multipart/form-data"
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
$ua->post("http://localhost:3000" => form => {Input_Type => "XML", Input_File => {file => "d:/xml/test.xml"}});
```

But this is [same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37675542/4632019) as:

```
perl -Mojo -E 'p("http://localhost:3000" => form => {Input_Type => "XML", Input_File => {file => "d:/xml/test.xml"}})'
```

**UPD**

To debug server side script for file uploading you should

```
perl -d uploadtest.pl daemon

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.49_04
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(tx.pl:6):    get '/' => 'form';
  DB<1>
```

This will bring you into [perl debugger](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) ([Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebtut.html))

```
  DB<1> l 1-30
1   #uploadtest.pl
2   
3:  use Mojolicious::Lite;
4   
5   # Upload form in DATA section
6==>    get '/' => 'form';
7   
8   
9   # Check status
10  post '/status' => sub {
11:   my $self = shift;
12:   my $Token = $self->param('Token');
13:   $self->render(text => "In process: $Token");
14: };
15  
16  # Multipart upload handler
17  post '/upload' => sub {
18:   my $self = shift;
19  
20    # Process uploaded file
21:   my $Input_File = $self->param('Input_File');
22:   my $Input_Type = $self->param('Input_Type');
23:   my $size = $Input_File->size;
24:   my $name = $Input_File->filename;
25:   my $upload = $self->req->upload('Input_File');
26:   $upload->move_to("d:/xml/$name");  #move location
27:   $self->render(text => "Thanks for uploading $size byte file $name.");
28: };
29  
30: app->start;
  DB<2> b 11
  DB<3> b 18
  DB<4> l 1-30
1   #uploadtest.pl
2   
3:  use Mojolicious::Lite;
4   
5   # Upload form in DATA section
6==>    get '/' => 'form';
7   
8   
9   # Check status
10  post '/status' => sub {
11:b      my $self = shift;
12:   my $Token = $self->param('Token');
13:   $self->render(text => "In process: $Token");
14: };
15  
16  # Multipart upload handler
17  post '/upload' => sub {
18:b      my $self = shift;
19  
20    # Process uploaded file
21:   my $Input_File = $self->param('Input_File');
22:   my $Input_Type = $self->param('Input_Type');
23:   my $size = $Input_File->size;
24:   my $name = $Input_File->filename;
25:   my $upload = $self->req->upload('Input_File');
26:   $upload->move_to("d:/xml/$name");  #move location
27:   $self->render(text => "Thanks for uploading $size byte file $name.");
28: };
29  
30: app->start;
  DB<5> c
[Tue Jun 14 16:43:06 2016] [info] Listening at "http://*:3000"
Server available at http://127.0.0.1:3000
[Tue Jun 14 16:43:10 2016] [debug] POST "/status"
[Tue Jun 14 16:43:10 2016] [debug] Routing to a callback
main::CODE(0x23f7be0)(tx.pl:11):      my $self = shift;
  DB<5> n
main::CODE(0x23f7be0)(tx.pl:12):      my $Token = $self->param('Token');
  DB<5> n
main::CODE(0x23f7be0)(tx.pl:13):      $self->render(text => "In process: $Token");
  DB<5> x $Token
0  '6d949625-2f07-1e7a-d57a-de0fa949035d'
  DB<6>
```

Here I list source from 1 to 30 line `l 1-30`, set two breakpoints `b 11` `b 18`, list source again `l 1-30` to see that breakpoints are in effect (Notice *b* near the line), run script from current point (Notice *==>* sign near the line) until next break point, done two steps with `n` command and view value of *$Token* variable with `x $Token` command.

Notice, that after `c` script wait interaction. I do that with `curl`

```
http://localhost:3000/status?Token=6d949625-2f07-1e7a-d57a-de0fa949035d
```

*NOTICE:* You should request '/status' and '/upload' **NOT** '/updater.pl/status' as you did. It has no matter for the outer word how your server script is named. Just only two things:

1. Where your script listen: localhost:3000
2. Which request may serve: '/upload' and '/status'

Comment: Yes, you are right, mojolicious get does not support file as argument . I want to debug my code which has file as a argument . curl is not supporting for this so i used mojolicious. But it does not have feature for same. Is there any alternative to debug my web service which is getting a file as argument?

Comment: I do not understand you. You want to debug server side script which allow file uploading or do file uploading with Mojo::UserAgent? If second I gave [the answer](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Large-file-upload) (This is same as `-F Input_File=@d:/xml/test.xml`)

Comment: yes, I want to debug server side script which allow file uploading.

Comment: @NeyazAhmad Hmmm... it seems my answer was useless =)